# Do AND, OR, NOT for multiple lists with complex data objects the pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-operations

I have multiple lists with complex objects. I want to do boolean operations **AND**, **OR**, **NOT** with them.

**AND**: The resulting list would contain all objects that existing in *all* used source lists. There should be no duplicates.

**OR**: The resulting list should contain all objects from all used source lists. There should be no duplicates.

**NOT**: The resuliting list should contain only existing objects from the source list that doesn't exist in the not-list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# the "complex data"
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # assume the 'name' as unique
        self.name = name

# create example data
mylistA = [Person('Anna'),
           Person('Bob'),
           Person('Jane'),
           Person('Alfred')]

mylistB = [Person('Simon'),
           Person('Anna'),
           Person('Doris'),
           Person('Bob')]

mylistC = [Person('Bob'),
           Person('Rosi'),
           Person('Becky'),
           Person('Anna')]

mylistD = [Person('Alfred'),
           Person('Bob'),
           Person('Chris'),
           Person('Susi')]

def doAND(some_lists):
    pass

def doOR(some_lists):
    pass

def doNOT(one_list, not_list):
    pass

# should result in 'Anna', 'Bob'
resultAND = doAND([mylistA, mylistB, mylistC])
print(resultAND)

# should result in 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Alfred', 'Simon', 'Doris', 'Rosi',
# 'Becky'
resultOR = doOR([mylistA, mylistB, mylistC])
print(resultOR)

# 'Anna'
resultNOT = doNOT(resultAND, mylistD)
print(resultNOT)
```

Background information: The "complex objects" are in the real scenario are sqlalchemy objects. Their "identity" in the context of my example here is not the primary key. Their "identity" is formed based on a cominbation of theire members (simple example: "firstname", "lastname", "birthdate").

Comment: You should implement an `__eq__` for your "complex data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @criket_007 who gave me the correct hint. Python is so easy! Just create operators for the *complexe data objects*. Then you can treat them as `set`.

That is the updated example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# the "complex data"
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # assume the 'name' as unique
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}:{}'.format(id(self), self.__str__())
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

# create example data
mylistA = [Person('Anna'),
           Person('Bob'),
           Person('Jane'),
           Person('Alfred')]
sa = set(mylistA)

mylistB = [Person('Simon'),
           Person('Anna'),
           Person('Doris'),
           Person('Bob')]
sb = set(mylistB)

mylistC = [Person('Bob'),
           Person('Rosi'),
           Person('Becky'),
           Person('Anna')]
sc = set(mylistC)

mylistD = [Person('Alfred'),
           Person('Bob'),
           Person('Chris'),
           Person('Susi')]
sd = set(mylistD)

# should result in 'Anna', 'Bob'
resultAND = sa.intersection(sb, sc)
print('AND: {}\n'.format(resultAND))

# should result in 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Alfred', 'Simon', 'Doris', 'Rosi',
# 'Becky'
resultOR = sa.union(sb, sc)
print('OR: {}\n'.format(resultOR))

# 'Anna'
resultNOT = resultAND.difference(sd)
print('NOT: {}\n'.format(resultNOT))
```

Comment: @lhk Please look at the histroy or timestamps. The __first version__ of your answer didn't fit my question. Thanks for your update. Thanks for your hint I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html), instead of a list.
This avoids duplicates and offers all of your operations in a convenient way:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,2,3]

a=set(a)
b=set(b)

# OR
a | b # [1,2,3,4,5]

# AND
a & b # [1,2,3]

# NOT
a - b # [4,5]
```

You can use this even for complex data types. They need to fulfill two criteria:

- `__eq__` needs to be implemented
- `__hash__`  needs to be implemented

The set needs `__eq__` to look for duplicates. But if you only implement `__eq__`, the default `__hash__` implementation will be removed.

That's because `__eq__` and `__hash__` need to be consistent.
So you need to reimplement `__hash__`

Your use of the builtin `hash()` function is actually much nicer than my version with hashlib. So I updated that.
Surprisingly, an implementation of `__hash__` doesn't provide an implicit implementation of `__eq__`, even though it is an invariant that objects with the same hash must be equal. Therefore, both `__eq__` and `__hash__` need to be implemented. That was wrong in a previous version of this answer.

Maybe the `__eq__` operator needs to be implemented again, because of performance reasons. I don't know how fast the `hash()` function is, but if your sets become large, it might be a useful optimization to compare the names directly, instead of hashing them first.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # assume the 'name' as unique
        self.name = name

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
        # return hash(self) == hash(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


persons = [Person("a"), Person("b"), Person("a")]

print(persons)  # [a, b, a]

persons_set= set(persons)

print(persons_set) # [a, b]
```

Comment: Doesn't fit my question where I asked for "complex data objects".

Comment: I think this fits quite well. If you need to avoid duplicates, you should define what a duplicate is. In python this is done with a hash function.

Comment: Here you implemented a `__eq__()`. Why? Do I need or not? Currentyl I am not able to test it. And why you didn't used `hash()` in `__hash()__`. What are the advanteges of your solution?

Comment: @Ihk Could you please describe why you implemented a `__eq__()` here.